# Seeking in HTML 5 video on safari / iOS

Tags: ios, html, video, safari

I have a video element, an mp4, that I am loading in a `<video>` tag for iOS. It looks like this:

```
<video width="640" height="360" controls="true" autoplay="false" tabindex="0" id="player"
src="http://wpc.xxxx.edgecastcdn.net/blahblah/movie.mp4">
</video>
```

This loads up and plays just fine. The problem is that I can't seek forward in this video; neither Safari nor iOS seem to be able to do this. Chrome will seek just fine, as does jwplayer (with correct configuration for edgecast).

What am I doing wrong, here?

Comment: How do you encode the .mp4 video?

Answer (score 0):

```
  http://www.inwebson.com/html5/custom-html5-video-controls-with-jquery/
```

Fast Forward, Slow Motion, and Rewind Controls

Yes, HTML5 video supports change of playback speed. We can change the video playback speed by changing the video playbackrate attribute.

```
<div class="control">
<a href="#" class="ff">Fast Forward</a>
<a href="#" class="rw">Rewind</a>
<a href="#" class="sl">Slow Motion</a>
</div>
```

Unfortunately, Firefox doesn’t support for playbackrate attribute yet. But partly for Chrome (doesn’t support negative value, which is rewind). So far only Safari fully supported.

```
//Fast forward control
 $('.ff').on('click', function() {
 video[0].playbackrate = 3;
 return false;
 });

 //Rewind control
 $('.rw').on('click', function() {
 video[0].playbackrate = -3;
 return false;
 });

 //Slow motion control
  $('.sl').on('click', function() {
  video[0].playbackrate = 0.5;
  return false;
  });


     http://www.digitaria.com/blogs/html5-video-skinning-tutorial-part-3-rewindfast-forward
       http://blogfreakz.com/html5/html5-video-players/
```

Comment: But iOS safari does not support playbackrate..refer this https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html